# What do the insignias on the collar shown in this photograph stand for?

Tags: military, identification, uniform, 1900s

Photo of my grandfather circa 1918-1945. He was born in Trieste and was in the merchant marines before jumping ship in US. Joined the US Army and was recruited as an agent for the OSS. Trying to determine the uniform he was wearing was and what the insignia on his collar represented. Anything will help!

[image: Picture of grandfather circa 1918 - 1945]

Comment: Not US in any way shape or form . . . perhaps Yugoslavian or Greek.

Comment: Out of curiosity: can you tell us anything about the provenance of that photograph? It appears to be halftone which suggests that it's a newspaper clipping, but at the same time it has a border with deckle edge and tears etc.: did you apply those using Photoshop or similar?

Comment: Canyou give a more precise timeframe than "circa 1918-1945." ? Given that your grandfather was certainly in his twenties when this photograph was, you can narrow the range for potential answerers...

Answer (score 29):

I believe this uniform is from the Austrio-Hungarian empire, WWI era.

Two six-pointed stars would indicate a [Korporal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korporal), and the exact unit insignia can be seen by scrolling down in the [pages shown](https://www.books-on-collectables.eu/index.php/en/militaria/uniforms-equipment-of-the-austro-hungarian-army-in-ww1/a-17702-37) (commercial site selling the book) for the book *Uniforms & Equipment of the Austro-Hungarian Army in WW1*.

The insignia represents a Trench Mortar unit, seen from a viewable version of the above book at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/the-austro-hungarian-forces-in-world-war-i-1916-18/page/n9/mode/2up)

[image]